# Rendering all fields of an entity (i.e. viewing the entity)

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to render all of the fields attached to a custom entity.  This will be used for "viewing" entity, like you would view a node or a user, etc.

I first tried to use [field_attach_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_view/7):

```
$fields = field_attach_view('contacts', $entity, 'full');
```

but it only gave me this:

```
[#pre_render] => Array
    (
        [0] => _field_extra_fields_pre_render
        [1] => field_group_build_pre_render
    )

[#entity_type] => contacts
[#bundle] => contacts
[#groups] => Array
    (
    )

[#fieldgroups] => Array
    (
    )

[#group_children] => Array
    (
    )
```

I also tried

```
$firstname = field_view_field('contacts', $entity, 'firstname');
```

But that gives me an empty array.

This is the controller:

```
class ContactsController extends EntityAPIController {

  public function create(array $values = array()) {
    global $user;
    $values += array(
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'uid' => $user->uid,
    );
    return parent::create($values);
  }

  public function buildContent($entity, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL, $content = array()) {

    // Trying to load a field
    $firstname = field_view_field('contacts', $entity, 'firstname', array());
    $content['firstname'] = $firstname;

    // Trying to load all of the fields
    field_attach_prepare_view('contacts', array($entity->ckid => $entity), 'full');
    $fields = field_attach_view('contacts', $entity, 'full');
    $content['contact'] = $fields;

    return parent::buildContent($entity, $view_mode, $langcode, $content);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** here is the entity:

```
[entityType:protected] => contacts
[entityInfo:protected] => Array
    (
        [label] => Contact
        [entity class] => Contacts
        [controller class] => ContactsController
        [base table] => contacts
        [fieldable] => 1
        [entity keys] => Array
            (
                [id] => ckid
                [bundle] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [revision] => 
            )

        [bundle keys] => Array
            (
            )

        [bundles] => Array
            (
                [contacts] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Contact
                        [rdf_mapping] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [load hook] => contacts_load
        [view modes] => Array
            (
                [full] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Default
                        [custom settings] => 
                    )

                [token] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Tokens
                        [custom settings] => 
                    )

            )

        [label callback] => entity_class_label
        [uri callback] => entity_class_uri
        [module] => contacts
        [access callback] => contacts_access
        [static cache] => 1
        [field cache] => 1
        [translation] => Array
            (
            )

        [schema_fields_sql] => Array
            (
                [base table] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ckid
                        [1] => firstname
                        [2] => lastname
                        [3] => publication
                        [4] => position
                        [5] => mail
                        [6] => phone
                        [7] => fax
                        [8] => street
                        [9] => city
                        [10] => state
                        [11] => zip
                        [12] => mobile_phone
                        [13] => home_phone
                        [14] => notes
                        [15] => alternate_mail
                        [16] => uid
                        [17] => created
                        [18] => changed
                    )

            )

        [token type] => contacts
        [configuration] => 
    )

[idKey:protected] => ckid
[nameKey:protected] => ckid
[statusKey:protected] => status
[ckid] => 1
[firstname] => Samuel
[lastname] => Adams
[publication] => Beers of the World
[position] => Programmer
[mail] => sam.adams@example.com
[phone] => 555-555-4321
[fax] => 
[street] => 4900 Barley Way
[city] => Fremont
[state] => CA
[zip] => 95555
[mobile_phone] => 555-555-1234
[home_phone] => 
[notes] => This is just a test contact.
[alternate_mail] => webmaster@example.com
[uid] => 1
[created] => 1354575373
[changed] => 1354575373
[rdf_mapping] => Array
    (
    )

[entity_view_prepared] => 1
```

Comment: Any chance you can add a dump of the `$entity` object as well?

Comment: It looks like the fields aren't attached to the entity when it's passed through to `field_attach_view()`...are you missing a call to [`field_attach_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) or [`field_attach_prepare_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_prepare_view/7) somewhere in the process?

Comment: Correct, I am not using field_attach_prepare_view at all... let me add that

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference, edited the question to include how I implemented it.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my configuration that is causing the field_attach_prepare_view to not load anything... I put added this same code to a page callback, but the field_attach_view showed the same thing.